# $p$ an odd prime and $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ such that $ab\equiv 1\mod p$. Show that legendre symbols $({a\over p}) = ({b\over p})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Need to prove $ab\equiv 1 \mod p \implies a\equiv b\mod p$

I know that the first statement implies that $b$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $p$ but can't see how that would prove the second statement.

I also know that from the first statement: $({ab\over p}) = ({1\over p}) = ({a\over p})\cdot( {b\over p})$ but again, stuck with what to do next...

Comment: What is $1/p$ equal to (When is $1$ a square mod $p$)? If $(a/p) * (b/p) = (1/p)$, what can you say now?

Comment: Your first sentence does not reflect the title.

Answer (score 1):

The Legendre symbol is multiplicative and takes values in $\{0, \pm 1\}$, hence neither of $\displaystyle\left({a\over p}\right),\left({b\over p}\right)$ is $0$ (since they multiply to $1$). And if exactly one of them is $-1$ the product is $-1$, so they must be equal.

Comment: Is the legendre symbol of 1/p always equal to 1?

Comment: @MargaretM yes:  by definition $\displaystyle\left({a\over p}\right)=1\iff a=b^2$ for some $b$ and $p\not | a$. But then clearly $1=1^2$ is a square.